# Tableau action filter not working issue

Tags: filter, tableau-api

As per my experience - In tableau for action filter to work the fields should meet two criteria.

```
1. Field should be a dimension.
2. Field has to be from same data sources. Blending and action filter dont work together.
```

Am I correct in saying that?

Comment: I found somewhere that if the data sources are blended, filter action will only work if the primary data source is same in source and target sheet. Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27748797/tableau-create-global-filter-from-a-secondary-data-source-to-multiple-data-sour

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct that is generally the rule of thumb. But, there are a couple of workarounds, however.

Method 1: Create a custom parameter and use it in a calculated field
Method 2: Create a control view for the field you want to filter on, and apply a filter action to that view on the dashboard

This is a [link](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/filter-data-sources) to a knowledge base article that details both methods mentioned.